# Highstock: how to define and make the x and y axes visible?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to make the y-axis visible using various ways, but every time I change the color of the axis the color of the whole graph i.e the series changes. Is there a way to make the y and x axes visible without changing the graph color.

```
xAxis: {
    gapGridLineWidth: 0
},

yAxis: {
    opposite:false,
},

navigator: {
    enabled:false,
},

rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
        type: 'hour',
        count: 1,
        text: '1h'
    }, {
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1D'
    }, {
        type: 'all',
        count: 1,
        text: 'All'
    }],
    selected: 1,
    inputEnabled: false,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change color of your axes without changing color of your series.

You can use tickColor, lineColor, gridLineColor and labels.style for setting colors of your label: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.lineColor

```
yAxis: {
      lineColor: 'red',
      gridLineColor: 'red',
      tickColor: 'red',
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      lineColor: 'red',
      tickColor: 'red',
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
},
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/c9bfmzsm/

Comment: for some reason linecolor is only working for the x-axis but not working for the y-axis

Comment: Where you have line on your yAxis? You need to set width of your line, in other case it will be 0. so you are changing color of line with 0 width. http://jsfiddle.net/c9bfmzsm/1/